# Oracle sqlplus HTML report - Changing row color based on one column Value

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, html-table

I am using Oracle sqlplus MARKUP HTML to convert query output into HTML report.

Is there any way to change row (Cell) color based on one column Value ? ( not the single column cell)

Column : RAG
Value : 
0 - ( Entire Row should apprear as white)

1 - ( Entire Row should apprear as YELLOW)

2 - ( Entire Row should apprear as RED)

3- ( Entire Row should apprear as GREEN)

```
SET VERIFY OFF 
SET TRIMSPOOL ON 
SET TRIMOUT ON 
SET FEEDBACK OFF 
SET HEADING ON 
SET ECHO OFF 
SET PAGES 150 
SET TERMOUT OFF

--TTITLE center 'Support - Check List' SKIP 2

Column "Start Time"  Format A10  Heading "Start Time|(UTC)"
Column APPLI         Format A11  Heading  Application
Column CHECK_DSC     Format A100 Heading "Check Description"
Column CHK_TYPE      Format A10  Heading "Check Type"
Column COMPLETED_BY  Format A10  Heading  Completed|By
Column "Completed Time" Format A10 Heading "Completed|Time(UTC)"



set markup html on spool on entmap off -
 head '<title>Support - Check List</title> -
 <style type="text/css"> -   
 table { background: #FFFFE0; font-size: 99%; } -
    th { background-color: DarkBlue;    color: white} -
    td { padding: 0px; } -  
</style>' -
 body 'text=black bgcolor=FAFAD2 align=left' -
 table 'align=center width=99% border=3 bordercolor=black bgcolor=white'

SPOOL chk.html
-- @ABC.txt

SELECT T1.CHK_ID ,
  TO_CHAR(FLOOR(ST_TIME/60),'00')  ||':'  ||TO_CHAR(MOD(T1.ST_TIME,60),'00') "Start Time",
  APPLI ,
  CHECK_DSC ,
  CHK_TYPE,
  COMPLETED_BY ,
  CASE
    WHEN COMPL_TIME IS NOT NULL 
    THEN TO_CHAR(FLOOR(COMPL_TIME/60),'00')      ||':'      ||TO_CHAR(MOD(COMPL_TIME,60),'00')
  END "Completed Time",
  RAG -- 0,1,2,3
FROM CHK_LIST T1,
  CHK_LOG T2
WHERE T1.CHK_ID=T2.CHK_ID ;


SPOOL off;
```